# How was Moaning Myrtle's death explained to her parents?

Tags: harry-potter

So, we know that Myrtle was killed by Salazar's Basilisk...

> “How?” said Harry.
>
> “No idea,” said Myrtle in hushed tones. “I just remember seeing a pair of great, big, yellow eyes. My whole body sort of seized up, and then I was floating away.
> …”

...but *wouldn't it have been extremely odd to explain to her parents that she was killed by a monster whilst in the loo?* He does say this to Riddle:

> “Precisely,” said the headmaster. “My dear boy, you must see
> how foolish it would be of me to allow you to remain at the castle
> when term ends. Particularly in light of the recent tragedy . . . the
> death of that poor little girl. . . . You will be safer by far at your orphanage.
> As a matter of fact, the Ministry of Magic is even now
> talking about closing the school. We are no nearer locating the —
> er — source of all this unpleasantness. . . .”

He simply called it a "tragedy", but I'd expect any parent to not be satisfied with such an answer.

#### So how exactly did Professor Dippet answer Myrtle's parents (and seemingly the student body as well) of her death?

Comment: "***Petrified to death. Cause unknown***", presumably.

Comment: How does anyone inform someone of a death when the source is unknown? Unless you can point to evidence that Dumbledore lied to the parents, it stands to reason that he communicated the certainty of her death but the uncertainty as to the cause (without causing a major alarm). But when speaking to Harry, he is more open about Harry's safety, as the source could still pose a danger to students in the school (but not the parents who live elsewhere)

Comment: @Flater What does Dumbledore have to do with it ? As the question even points out Dumbledore wasn't headmaster then - it was Dippet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering Hagrid and Aragog were officially blamed for the incident, it would seem likely that is the story Myrtle's parents were told.

Something like: *"Your daughter was killed by an Acromantula that another student had brought into school. The student has been expelled."*

Short and "factual"...